# Java Arrays as Parameters

Tags: java, arrays

Can you pass a new array as a method, and still have data in that array?

For example, I have this method: `foo(String[])`, and i want to call it like this`foo(new String[] s = {"String1", "String2"})`. But that's not valid Java.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a "valid Java way" (as in, it compiles and does what you want):

```
foo(new String[] {"String1", "String2"});
```

If you have the opportunity to change this method, then you can also consider to change the method to take a [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) argument:

```
public void foo(String... strings) {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can use it as follows without the need to explicitly create an array:

```
foo("String1", "String2");
```

The following is then also valid:

```
foo("String1");
```

and

```
foo("String1", "String2", "String3");
```

and even more.

Comment: How to get the vaue then?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to make a local variable `s` and keep it around, no, you can't declare a variable within a method call. You have to declare it first outside of the call:

```
String[] s = {"String1", "String2"};
foo(s);
```

You *could* initialize `s` within the call, but I don't see any reason to do so, plus it looks really bad:

```
String[] s;
foo(s = new String[] {"String1", "String2"});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass only the value and don't need the variable `s` anymore, do it like this:

```
foo(new String[] {"String1", "String2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable, but you can pass an array:

```
foo(new String[] { "String1", "String2" });
```

If you want to reference the same array later, then you need to declare it before the call.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do foo(new String []{"String1","String2"})